# Visual Studio 2015 Asp.net 5.0 Dynamic development does not work in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

So I installed VS2015 CTP6. In the blog of Scott it advertises:

*Dynamic Development.
In Visual Studio 2015, we take advantage of dynamic compilation to provide a streamlined developer experience. You no longer have to compile your application every time you want to see a change. Instead, just (1) edit the code, (2) save your changes, (3) refresh the browser, and then (4) see your change automatically appear.*

Well, if I do that visual studio kills the browser on the save action.
What am I doing wrong?

Created a new project, asp.net 5 and switched runtime to coreclr. Tried IIS express & "web"..

Comment: It does work when I start "without debugging".. someone please tell me that it also is supposed to work when debugging.. if this only works without debugging would be a real bummer..

Comment: you should post this at the official thread: https://github.com/aspnet/Home

Comment: But is not a framework issue in my opinion its visual studio

Comment: theres a thread for VS as well!

Comment: Can you point me to it? Can't find it on the url you provided, thanks

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/tooling

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The new edit & continue functionality for Roslyn currently does not work with the debugger attached. This will be fixed in a future release. You can start without debugging (ctrl + F5) if you want edit & continue support.

Comment: This really needs to be documented within the blog post / noted in the talks. I just wasted 2 hours guessing and trying to install /update stuff because of this until finally I used the right words in Google and got here.
(assuming you work at Microsoft...)

Comment: I just wasted 2 days for it.